# How to secure a simple Node.js RESTful API

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, oauth, jwt

i'm developing a simple news App where users can see latest news without login, i don't know how to make it secure, i have read that JWT with OAuth2 should be used but from my understanding the user have to login into a provider to get the token but i want users to be able to read data without login.
my concern right now is how to prevent other people from using my API in their apps, i'm concerned also about DoS attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### THE CHALLENGE

> i'm developing a simple news App where users can see latest news without login, i don't know how to make it secure

Well you bought yourself a really huge challenge, because even if you required your users to login, it would continue to be a huge challenge, because the web as we know was designed in their earlier days with the naive assumption that only good faith people would use it, thus it becomes a very hard task to secure something that was not designed to be secure in first place.

Securing and locking an API server to a specific app requires that some kind of secret needs to be used in every request in order to authenticate **What** is doing the request, but once you release a web app or mobile app into the public any secret on it is now in the public domain, therefore not a secret anymore, as it's best you can use it as a weak identifier.

#### Web App

A web app runs in the browser, thus all an attacker needs to do is to inspect the page source and extract the secret, and then use it in automated scripts or in manual requests from `curl` or tools like Postman.

#### Mobile App

Some developers think that because a mobile app is released as a binary that they can just put the secret there and no one will find it... Well I have to say that in the past I was one of them, but then I came to learn that a lot of open source tools exist to make this task trivial that even a script kid can do it. My preferred tool to do this is the [MobSF](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF), and you can see an example of using it in this article I wrote [How to Extract an API Key from a Mobile App with Static Binary Analysis](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-extract-an-api-key-from-a-mobile-app-with-static-binary-analysis):

> The range of open source tools available for reverse engineering is huge, and we really can't scratch the surface of this topic in this article, but instead we will focus in using the Mobile Security Framework(MobSF) to demonstrate how to reverse engineer the APK of our mobile app. MobSF is a collection of open source tools that present their results in an attractive dashboard, but the same tools used under the hood within MobSF and elsewhere can be used individually to achieve the same results.

[MobSF - Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF):

> Mobile Security Framework is an automated, all-in-one mobile application (Android/iOS/Windows) pen-testing framework capable of performing static analysis, dynamic analysis, malware analysis and web API testing.

The take away is that once an app is released any sensitive information shipped within it must be considered compromised.

### JWT and OAUTH2

> i have read that JWT with OAuth2 should be used but from my understanding the user have to login into a provider to get the token

Yes, the user would be required to login to get the OAuth token, but any type of token that comes from a user login successfully just identifies **Who** is in the request, not **What** is doing the request, and in my experience this is a very common misconception among developers, no matter if they are a junior or a senior developer.

#### The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

I wrote a series of articles about Mobile API security, and in the article [Why Does Your Mobile App Need An Api Key?](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key#api-who-vs-what) you can read in detail the difference between **Who** and **What** is making the reques to your API server:

> The **what** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of your mobile app, or is it a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?
>
> The **who** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

You may be surprised that sometimes even your legit users may be the ones attacking your API server in order to try to get benefits from your service that otherwise they wouldn't have access.

### SECURING AND LOCKING THE API SERVER TO AN APP

> but i want users to be able to read data without login.
> my concern right now is how to prevent other people from using my API in their apps

To achieve this requirements in your app you need to find ways to secure and lock your API server to only serve requests from genuine instances of your web and mobile apps.

I have to say that for mobile apps this can be achieved with a very high degree of confidence when a Mobile App Attestation concept is employed, but for web apps we just can do it in a best effort basis, by using Artificial Intelligence solutions.

To understand how you can do it for a web app please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146427/secure-api-data-from-calls-out-of-the-app) I gave to the question *Secure api data from calls out of the app*, specifically the section entitled *Defending The API Server*.

For a mobile app you should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605789/6454622) I gave to the question *How to secure an API REST for mobile app?*, more specifically at the section *Securing the API Server* and the section *A Possible Better Solution*.

If you have read both the answers I linked above you may understand now better why I said initially that was a *huge challenge*.

### DoS ATTACKS

> u'm concerned also about DoS attacks.

This is not normally addressed at the application level, instead it his best handled at the infrastructure level, like in the Firewall, where rules can be applied to identify and drop DoS packets, but if they are to strict they may also block legit users, while if they are too relaxed they let pass DoS packets. To have more effective DoS attacks protections you need to resort to specialized software, and even this ones may need manual intervention during an huge scale DoS attack.

So my advice here is that you start by adding to the Firewall some rules to drop DoS packets, and/or if you are using a cloud provider you may want to see what level of DoS protection they can offer in your account. I know for example that some CDN providers do offer DoS protection for free until some extent, thus may worth you consider to have all your traffic routed through a CDN, that also brings the other traditional benefits of a CDN, aka serving assets from a closest location to your customers.

### DO YOU WANT TO GO THE EXTRA MILE?

In any response to a security question I don't resist to reference the excellent work from the OWASP foundation.

#### For Web Apps

[OWASP Web Top 10 Risks](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf)

> The OWASP Top 10 is a powerful awareness document for web application security. It represents a broad consensus about the most critical security risks to web applications. Project members include a variety of security experts from around the world who have shared their expertise to produce this list.

[The Web Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/wstg):

> The OWASP Web Security Testing Guide includes a "best practice" penetration testing framework which users can implement in their own organizations and a "low level" penetration testing guide that describes techniques for testing most common web application and web service security issues.

#### For Mobile Apps

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

[OWASP - Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg):

> The Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG) is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security development, testing and reverse engineering.

#### For APIS

[OWASP API Security Top 10](https://github.com/OWASP/API-Security)

> The OWASP API Security Project seeks to provide value to software developers and security assessors by underscoring the potential risks in insecure APIs, and illustrating how these risks may be mitigated. In order to facilitate this goal, the OWASP API Security Project will create and maintain a Top 10 API Security Risks document, as well as a documentation portal for best practices when creating or assessing APIs.