# Detect Request sent from Postman

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I want to make a request to verify people's ID using laravel. Since it's very credential, I want to make it available only if they verify it from their mobiles.
So it must be prevented that the IDs are verified from postman request.
Is there a way to detect that a request is sent from postman or not?

Any idea would be very appreaciated :).
Thank you before

Answer (score 3):

Postman has a tendency to send a header called something like `postman-token` so you could block the request if such a header exists.

*Edit* Note that this header can be turned off in postman settingss

As @EdwardChew wrote, this does NOT prevent people from using postman/curl/python/anything else. adding  authentication to the endpoint is the best approach.

Sample postman request:

```
GET /api/car HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 05f5c492-3697-41b1-be0f-fb9bc4499b96
```

Since postman has the "code" feature, if the request is blocked it is simple to copy it as a curl command:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:8080/api/car \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: e37790ea-a3a5-40cf-ac4c-b80184801f94' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

and just deleting the line with the `Postman-Token` header. I normally do so when experimenting with APIs.

If you look at the Laravel doucmentation, there is a section on authorization: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication 
which would force users to add a header token something like this: `Authorization: Bearer 8fyew8f9yefo7o9yg98gyr` and you would then be able to verify the caller

Comment: The `postman-token` is an optional token that can be disabled via the settings menu so I wouldn't rely on that property for any of your workflows.

Comment: good point, i think the consensus is authentication is the best approach

Answer (score 3):

> So it must be prevented that the IDs are verified from postman request.
> Is there a way to detect that a request is sent from postman or not?

Checking that it comes from Postman is easy for requests sent from Postman where the boxes are checked for `Postman-Token` and/or `User-Agent`:

[image: postman headers]

So you would add a check for them in your backend, but then the attacker would not send the `Postman-Token` header and for the `User-Agent` we will just send exactly the same one your mobile app/browser sends, thus easily bypassing your checks. By the way Postman is not the only tool, others exist like Insomnia, and then you also need to remember that requests may also come from a Proxy like mitmproxy, burp, zap, charlie, and many others. Do you get the point... it's not feasible to rely on headers to identify **what** is doing the request.

I highlighted the word `what` because **who** is in the request for your API backend is not the same as **what** is doing it.

#### The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

In an article I wrote, entitled [Why Does Your Mobile App Need An Api Key?](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key#api-who-vs-what) you can read more about the difference between **who** and **what** is accessing your API server, but i will I quote the following from it:

> The **what** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of your mobile app, or is it a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?
>
> The **who** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

So the **who** is the user of your API server that you will be able to Authenticate and Authorize access to the data, and the **what** is the software making that request in behalf of the user, your genuine web/mobile app, a tampered one, an automated script or someone manually poking around with your API via cURL, **Postman** or other similar tools.

By now I hope that you have enough knowledge to understand why the user(*who*) authentication is not the same as app(*what*) authentication/attestation.

### POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS

> I want to make a request to verify people's ID using laravel. Since it's very credential, I want to make it available only if they verify it from their mobiles.

It's not clear if you mean from a mobile browser or mobile app, but I will provide possible solutions for both.

#### For Mobile Apps

To learn how you can lock your API server to your mobile app I recommend you to read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559419/how-to-secure-an-api-rest-for-mobile-app-if-sniffing-requests-gives-you-the-k/60605789#60605789) to the question **How to secure an API REST for mobile app?** for the sections on *Securing the API Server* and *A Possible Better Solution*.

#### For web apps

Due to the nature of how the web was built, all you need is to hit F12 or inspect the page source, and then search for whatever you need to access the API server from another tool.

To learn some useful techniques to try that your API server only responds to requests coming from **What** you expect, your genuine web app, I invite you to read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146427/secure-api-data-from-calls-out-of-the-app/61188785#61188785) to the question **Secure api data from calls out of the app**, specially the section dedicated to *Defending the API Server*.

### DO YOU WANT TO GO THE EXTRA MILE?

I don't know if you already read some of the OWASP resources I am about to link, but in any response for a security question I like to reference the amazing work from the OWASP foundation ;)

#### For Web Apps

[OWASP Web Top 10 Risks](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf)

> The OWASP Top 10 is a powerful awareness document for web application security. It represents a broad consensus about the most critical security risks to web applications. Project members include a variety of security experts from around the world who have shared their expertise to produce this list.

[The Web Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/wstg):

> The OWASP Web Security Testing Guide includes a "best practice" penetration testing framework which users can implement in their own organizations and a "low level" penetration testing guide that describes techniques for testing most common web application and web service security issues.

#### For Mobile Apps

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

[OWASP - Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg):

> The Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG) is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security development, testing and reverse engineering.

#### For APIS

[OWASP API Security Top 10](https://github.com/OWASP/API-Security)

> The OWASP API Security Project seeks to provide value to software developers and security assessors by underscoring the potential risks in insecure APIs, and illustrating how these risks may be mitigated. In order to facilitate this goal, the OWASP API Security Project will create and maintain a Top 10 API Security Risks document, as well as a documentation portal for best practices when creating or assessing APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of detecting whether the request comes from Postman, it is better for you to protect the endpoint with authentication. 
With this, even tho the user submitted a request through postman, you can still make sure that it is the user itself who made the request.

Please do let me know if there are actually other concerns bothering you. Cheers :)

Comment: What I really mean is how to make sure that the verification request is sent from the app endpoint only (directly from the app from their smartphone)
So if this particular request is sent from Postman or any other REST API tools instead of smartphone, it will result to fail or unauthorized request. 
is it possible?

Comment: If you really want to achieve this, I would suggest to add in a secret key in your application. When you make any request, encrypt your body with the secret key and decrypt the body at your server. This will increase the difficulty to send imitate request but still it is possible to reverse engineer and get your app secret key, just much tougher.

Comment: @Ardi Tan you should update your question stating that what your after is to detect that the request is indeed from the mobile app, because that totally changes the scope of your question.