# Protect a public API

Tags: api, security

After reading around it appears that trying to protect a publically accessible API (API used by an app/site that does not need a user to log in) appears to be fruitless, e.g. store key in app, user can reverse engineer app.

My question relates to how one can protect as much as possible and slow down abuse of a public accessible API...

Rate-limiting? Check request origin (although can be spoofed).... anything else?

Also if the site is SSR, could it just be protected by the server's IP?

Comment: You can certainly protect API's for sites, right? E.g. you can require TLS client authentication. For apps it is harder; you'd need to run them within a trusted environment to make sure that the key cannot be retrieved (or the trust store / whilelist to be altered).

Answer (score 22):

### YOUR QUESTIONS?

> After reading around it appears that trying to protect a publically accessible API (API used by an app/site that does not need a user to log in) appears to be fruitless, e.g. store key in app, user can reverse engineer app.

Security is all about defense in depth, thus is all about adding as many layers as you can afford and required by law in order to mitigate the risk, therefore any defense you add it's one more layer that will prevent that simple/dumb automated scripts from accessing it, while at same time will increase the level of skills and effort necessary for an hacker poking around to overcome all defenses.

> Rate-limiting?

This is kind of mandatory for any API to employ, otherwise an automated script can easily extract an huge amount of data in seconds. The more strict this rate limit is applied, the greater may be the chances for other layers of defense to detect that unauthorized access to the API may be happening and try to mitigate/block it. To bear in mind that the rate limits can be bypassed by adapting the attack to make requests that do not trigger it, and in some cases easily automated for that Software that give back in the response header the throttling values being applied.

> Check request origin (although can be spoofed)....

Yest it is easily bypassed, but why not? It will be one more layer of defense that filters out some dumb automated scripts/bots.

> Also if the site is SSR, could it just be protected by the server's IP?

No matter if a SSR site or any other type of app, when used from a mobile phone the IP address can change during the load of a page or mobile app screen, because when the phone switches between masters the IP will change. Also to bear in mind that in an office or public wifi all the users on it will have the same IP.

The use of it as a blocking measure on its own needs to be carefully evaluated, and normally requires fingerprinting the request in order to reduce the risk of blocking other valid users sharing the same network.

I would use it very carefully to avoid/block/throttle requests only when I could establish that hey are known bad IPs, that you can collect from your own requests history and/or from public datasets.

### WHO IS IN THE REQUEST VS WHAT IS MAKING THE REQUEST

A common misconception around developers of any seniority is about not being aware that the **who** is in the request is not the same as **what** is making the request, therefore we will first clear it out...

#### The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

While your API is not using user authentication is important to be aware of this distinction in order to better perform informed decisions around the security measures to be adapted in the API server.

I wrote a series of articles about API and Mobile security, and in the article [Why Does Your Mobile App Need An Api Key?](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key#api-who-vs-what) you can read in more detail the difference between **who** and **what** is accessing your API server, but I will quote here the main takes from it:

> The **what** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of your mobile app, or is it a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?

> The **who** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

The best way to remember the difference is to think about the **who** as the user your API server will be able to Authenticate and Authorize access to the data, and think about the **what** as the software making that request in behalf of the user.

### DEFENDING THE API SERVER

> My question relates to how one can protect as much as possible and slow down abuse of a public accessible API...

#### For Mobile APIs

For an API serving only mobile apps you can use the Mobile App Attestation concept as I describe in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605789/6454622) to the question *How to secure an API REST for mobile app?*.

#### For Web APPs

For an API that only serves a Web app I would recommend you to read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61188785/6454622) to the question *secure api data from calls out of the app?*.

### DO YOU WANT TO GO THE EXTRA MILE?

> anything else?

It seems you already have done some research but you may not know yet the OWASP guides and top risks.

#### For Web Apps

[The Web Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/wstg):

> The OWASP Web Security Testing Guide includes a "best practice" penetration testing framework which users can implement in their own organizations and a "low level" penetration testing guide that describes techniques for testing most common web application and web service security issues.

#### For Mobile Apps

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

[OWASP - Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg):

> The Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG) is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security development, testing and reverse engineering.

#### For APIS

[OWASP API Security Top 10](https://github.com/OWASP/API-Security)

> The OWASP API Security Project seeks to provide value to software developers and security assessors by underscoring the potential risks in insecure APIs, and illustrating how these risks may be mitigated. In order to facilitate this goal, the OWASP API Security Project will create and maintain a Top 10 API Security Risks document, as well as a documentation portal for best practices when creating or assessing APIs.

Answer (score 1):

#### Just for a quick answer

I can suggest at least one via solution which is to use an **API Gateway** (like [Kong](https://konghq.com/), [Express Gateway](https://www.express-gateway.io/) or [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/), etc.).

The API Gateway allows you to create API consumers (e.g: buyer mobile app, seller mobile app, buyer TV app). For each API consumer, an auth key (or even OAuth 2.0 credentials) will be generated and asigned respectively.

You then can use the auth key or OAuth 2.0 credentials (ID and secret) to access the APIs securely (even for the public ones, as API Gateways will only allow access from valid API consumers).

#### How about request from web?

You can configure API Gateway to detect requests from web and instead of using auth key or Oauth mechanism, it can use domain white-listing CORS protection mechanism.

#### How about user access token (generated from successful login)? Any conflict here?

IMHO (emphasized), after getting user access token (e.g: a JWT), for every authenticated-user-only requests you will send both API Gateway auth key token user auth access token. Referencing to Exadra's answer above, we can consider API Gateway key is to verify the "what" (mobile app) while user access token is to verify the "who" (login user).

Comment: "it can use domain white-listing CORS protection mechanism" can you elaborate on this? client ips change all the times and the requests come from all over the world, how can you restrict call via cors ?

Comment: You whitelist the domain, not the IP address. E.g: You backend server (api.abc.com) will only allow access (AJAX calls) from your web (abc.com).

Comment: And what exactly is stopping me from piggybacking on your web and send as many requests to your server. Truly for open APIs (Public APIs) you can only do stuff like Rate Limit, DPI, Network layer intelligent IDS etc.